# Show Urls instead of images Android app

Tags: java, android, image, android-layout, listview

I'm trying to create a simple app that loading photos from a website (like 9gag). I'm using jSoup and asyncTask. The problem is when I'm running the app it shows me only the urls of the images.. what can I do in order to display the image in the listView and not the urls.
XML Prob? Help :-/

![Screen Shot]https://www.dropbox.com/s/moybisjrbdgzjre/Screenshot_2013-04-29-20-09-13.png

here's my LoadImages class:

```
public LoadImages(ArrayList list, ArrayAdapter adapter)
{

    this.list = list;
    this.adapter = adapter;
}

@Override
protected Elements doInBackground(String... params) {
     org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = null;
        try
        {
            doc =Jsoup.connect("http://mongol.co.il/").get();
            return  doc.select("img");

        }
        catch (IOException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Elements result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    int flag=0;
    //Bitmap bitmap = null;
    for ( org.jsoup.nodes.Element div : result )
    {
        String bla = div.absUrl("src");
        list.add(bla);
        flag++;
        if(flag==3)
        break;

    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Here's also my .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
  android:orientation="vertical"  
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ListView 
     android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

 </ListView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks In advance!

Answer (score 0):

You're only fetching the URLs at this point. You need to fetch the actual Bitmap data in order to show images. There are two ways to do this:

1. Download all the images, then show the list after everything is fetched
2. Show the list immediately with image placeholders, the fetch the images as they're
   needed

In general, it's a better experience to respond quickly by showing what you have as you get it (option #2). A ListView is really conducive to this model. In the getView() method of the adapter you'll show the placeholder image while firing off an AsyncTask to get the bitmap. You'll then set Image in onPostExecute. Unfortunately things get messy with View recycling. This basic implementation will result in the wrong image being shown in many cases and a totally unresponsive device if the user scrolls back and forth quickly.

Fortunately, these are problems that others have solved. In fact, there is an excellent set of [tutorials along with sample code on Android Developer website](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this:

I have a `DB` with `ID`, `image URL`, `image URI`

`image URI` is something like `file:////mnt/sdcard/<your package>/images/image1.png`

I have a place Holder image for each row and in my `Arraylist` i have put `image URI` in `Arraylist`. then in `getView` method check if that `URI file` exists or not if not then send a broadcast to download that image(with ID). In downloader I fetch images with corresponding URL.

**How to check URI exists**: create a file object with URI and call `isExists()`

**How to send broadcast**: create an `intent` put `ID` in `extras` then call `sendBroadcast(intent)`

**Now how to refresh list after image has been download**: Send another `broadcast` from `onPostExecute()` to refresh list and catch that `broadcast` in your `activity` and call `list.notifyDatasetChanged()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding String to the list

```
 String bla = div.absUrl("src");
 list.add(bla);
```

You need to create `custom adapter`  (for the `ListView`), which will take that `String bla` and *download* the image.

Try this [tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter)