# Display Image in a Listview (In Adapter) using Json

Tags: android, json, image, listview

Please bear with me before downvoting this.I am a beginner to Android. After trying multiple solutions on here I have failed to resolve this.

I am trying to set the Image in the listview with the following items in place.I want to be able to insert the image code somewhere on the Schedule adapter class.

The following code is my Schedule Adapter

```
public class Schedule_ArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Activity activity;
    private final String[] name, category, image;
    Typeface colab, colab_bold, Bebas;
    int selected = -1;

public Schedule_ArrayAdapter(Activity activity, String[] name, String[] category, String[] image) {
    super(activity, R.layout.schedule_item, category);
    this.activity = activity;
    this.name = name;
    this.category = category;
    this.image = image;


    this.colab = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "ColabThi.otf");
    this.colab_bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "ColabMed.otf");
    this.colab_bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "BebasNeue.otf");
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    //get view and textview from xml
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_item, parent, false);
    rowView.setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
    LinearLayout background = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.back);
    if (selected != -1) {
        if (selected == position) {
            background.setBackgroundColor(0xffeaac4b);
        } else {
            background.setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
        }
    }else{
        background.setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
    }

    TextView TimeView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.category);
    TextView TitleView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    ImageView vi = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);

    GetImage getimage = new GetImage();
    getimage.execute(image);

    //change names
    TitleView.setText(category[position]);
    TitleView.setTextSize(fontpercent_screenheight(3.5));
    TitleView.setPadding(dp(10), dp(5), dp(5), dp(0));
    TitleView.setTypeface(Bebas);

    TimeView.setText(name[position]);
    TimeView.setTextSize(fontpercent_screenheight(3.5));
    TimeView.setPadding(dp(10), dp(2), dp(5), dp(5));
    TimeView.setTypeface(colab);

    return rowView;
}
```

The following is my ImageDownloader class

```
public class ImageDownloader {
    private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String image) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = null;
    int response = -1;

    URL url = new URL(image);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
        throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

    conn.setUseCaches(true);
    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
    try {
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect();
        response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            in = httpConn.getInputStream();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new IOException("Error connecting" + ex);
    }
    return in;
}

public Bitmap DownloadImage(String image) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = OpenHttpConnection(image);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;
}
}
```

Parsing of JSON and fetching Data is working as normal. When looking in the debugger the "image" array is also been fetched. How do i set the images in the view ?
[image]

Comment: Hi can you add Android Tag on your question? Thanks!

Comment: so are you trying to create a listview with image on it with some text and category? is that what you want to do?

Comment: @cafebabe1991 yes. Absoluteluy. Just that I am stumped at what code to actually display the image in my schedule adapter

Comment: see below for a short answer...

Comment: @cafebabe1991 where below ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16621410/1270865....JUST BELOW :-P

Comment: @cafebabe1991 see my comment below.

Comment: This is exactly same what I did in my project. Please go to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16312895/1221797) and check my answer. The good thing is you have to download images only once and no one else can copy them(Unless device is rooted)

Answer (score 0):

So in your getView of the `adapter` you should make a request to some url and use the

Bitmap bitmap=`BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputstream);`

now set this in your imageview of your layout

```
ImageView i=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageiew);
i.setImageResource(bitmap);
```

so that shows the image.

Comment: My issue is that I have an array of strings that are the URL. So my array is called image[] which has about 53 URLS.'

Comment: Hello Sam, Why dont you set image Bitmap to your imageView vi? You will get the array position in the getview method.

Comment: Hi @zangeed. Sorry I am a bit lost. Can you explain by pointing it out in my code . Maybe with corrections in my code ?

Comment: So you should call your ImageDownloader class and use its downloadImage method to return you the image inside your getView method...and set it on the imageView  ...ImageView vi = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imgPreview); vi.setImageResource(image returned by the DownloadImage method  of image downloader class);

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this code

```
ImageView iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    try {
        iv.setImageDrawable(grabImageFromUrl(Global.a5));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the function of fetching image from URL is

```
    private Drawable grabImageFromUrl(String url) throws Exception {
        return Drawable.createFromStream((InputStream)new URL(url).getContent(), "src");  }
```